# remove all UIButtons from view?

Tags: ios, objective-c, cocos2d-iphone

I am having a hard time removing all UIButtons from view .

I have added them to `UIScrollView` in a for loop, and later on i need to remove them.

so to add them : (over a cocos2d scene)

```
sview = [[UIScrollView alloc]
                          initWithFrame:[[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds]];

......
for(int i =0; i<[assets count]-1; i++)  
    {

        UIImage *thumb= [assets objectAtIndex:i];
        UIButton * button = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeCustom];
               [sview addSubview:button];
.......
 [[[CCDirector sharedDirector] view] addSubview:sview];
```

and to remove them :

```
[((UIView *)sview) removeFromSuperview]; //which usually works but no now .
```

How would i run on all this buttons later and remove them ?
i dont have link to them ,and i would like to run on all buttons in view ..

**EDIT : HAVE TRIED THIS WITHOUT SUCCESS**

```
for (int i=0; i<[assets count];i++)
    {
        UIButton *myButton = (UIButton *)[sview viewWithTag:i];
         [((UIView *)myButton) removeFromSuperview];
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are a couple ways to do. Some people have suggested one way. I personally like to keep all the things I add in an `NSMutableArray` (add then to the array when you add them to your view), then just loop through the array to remove them.

```
for ( ... ; ... ; ...) {
    UIButton *button = ....
    // in your "add button loop" just record them in an array
    [self.transientViews addObject:button];
}


// remove them later with
for (UIView *view in self.transientViews)
    [view removeFromSuperview];
[self.transientViews removeAllObjects];
```

I like this because it gives me a lot more flexibility. I might want to remove them or something else. They could be any sub-class of `UIView` and I don't have to worry about it.

Comment: the sview background is not going away,but all buttons are go. i tried to take him away with    [((UIView *)sview) removeFromSuperview]; which worked for buttons, but it still there. i NSlog it  to see that i have a link to him, and i am getting his values.

Answer (score 2):

While technically possible, it's not a good idea to design your code like this.

> i dont have link to them

Here lies your problem. Put them in an `NSMutableArray` as you create and add them, then iterate over this array for removing them.

However, if, for some reason, you don't do that, you can just check all the subviews of your view for being an UIButton:

```
- (void)removeUIButtonsFromView:(UIView *v)
{
    for (UIView *sub in v.subviews) {
        if ([sub isKindOfClass:[UIButton class]]) {
            [sub removeFromSuperview];
        } else {
            [self removeUIButtonsFromView:sub];
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I have tried that i get warnning on the for loop : collection expression type on uiscrollview may not respond to countByEnumerating......

Comment: @user1994291 Then you screwed up something.

Comment: Note that use of abbreviations in Cocoa is considered bad style.

Comment: @NikolaiRuhe Noted, ignored. (for the readability of the answer.)

Comment: @H2CO3 The readability of the answer would raise the same amount as other code by using names like `view` rather than `v`.

Answer (score 1):

```
for (UIView *subview in [((UIView *)sview).subviews copy]) {
    if ([subview isKindOfClass:[UIButton class]])
        [subview removeFromSuperview];
}
```

Comment: @user1994291 Stop complaining and make an effort understanding your own code, then add the code in one of the provided to a place and in a way that makes sense. It will then work.

Comment: i can see that they got some opacity and i can barely see them in background...something is really bad here ...

Answer (score 1):

If it's only buttons in the scroll view, remove them all with:

```
[sview.subviews makeObjectsPerformSelector:@selector(removeFromSuperview)];
```

Comment: `makeObjectsPerformSelector` is indeed a neat method :)

Comment: This probably isn't the "right answer" for OP, but that's a nice trick! Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

```
[((UIView *)sview) removeFromSuperview]
```

You're removing the scrollview `sview` : why ?

When you add the buttons, just add them also to a `NSArray` property you keep around.
Then just iterate on that array whenver you want to remove them

```
//in your interface

@property (nonatomic, strong) NSArray *buttons;

//in your implementation

sview = [[UIScrollView alloc]
                          initWithFrame:[[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds]];

......
NSMutableArray *tempArray = [NSMutableArray array];
for(int i =0; i<[assets count]-1; i++)  
    {

        UIImage *thumb= [assets objectAtIndex:i];
        UIButton * button = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeCustom];
               [sview addSubview:button];
        [tempArray addObject:button];
    }
    self.buttons = tempArray;
.......

// later, to remove all buttons

- (void) removeButtons
{
    for(UiButton *button in self.buttons){
        [button removeFromSuperview];
    }
    self.buttons = nil;
}
```